# Possible to retrieve key-values result list from AD using LDAP?

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I would need to retrieve a certain attribute value from AD for a list of persons. Can this be done in one request, or do I need to make as many requests as there are persons for whom this attribute is to be retrieved?

search scope is wholeSubtree

I should also be able to identify the attribute value to its corresponding person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transmit a search request to the directory server using the appropriate base object, scope, the list of attribute values required, and a filter that will match all the entries in the list. The directory server will return search results - one for each entry returned, if any - an integer describing the results of the search request, and an integer with the number of entries returned, if any. Each search result will contain the distinguished name of the entry and the attributes that were requested, assuming the access controls for the authorization state of the connection allows the attribute values to be returned.

#### see also

- [LDAP: Mastering Search Filters](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/09/21/mastering-ldap-search-filters/)
- [LDAP: Search best practices](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/ldap-search-best-practices.html)
- [LDAP: Programming practices](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/10/27/ldap-programming-best-practices/)